# Is it a good practice to store spring.security.* properties in configuration server?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud-config

Is it a good practice to store spring.security.* properties, used by SpringBoot app, in configuration server? There are two problems that bothers me:

- in case of lack of conectivity, can application boot without any security at all?
- can any potential attacker trigger context refres (if I understand correctly spring will refresh all beans and configurations) and in case of lack of conectivity the security will be gone?

Comment: The easy way to find out if your app will start without Spring Security properties is to try to start your app without configuration properties and see what happens. You can also have your app throw an exception during initialization if it can't load a property from the configuration server (so the app won't start).  If an attacker can take down your config server and refresh your app then the attacker already has enough access to get your data without doing those things (plus more info can be extracted from a fully-initialized Java process).

Comment: Good idea, the app indeed does not boot.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the part 3 of the [12 factor app](https://12factor.net/config) principle, you should store your configuration on the environment (your server).

As an example, when deploying your application on the cloud, you have the concept of *[secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/basic-concepts)* that are crypted values you store in your server such as: credentials, passwords, keys etc...

Comment: *that are crypted values you store in your server* That is not quite right: it is stored on a different server and not in environment variable as 12 factor app recommended. However, both concepts are widely used.